# What is the smallest standard CNC tool holder

Tags: cnc, drilling

I am looking at making a small CNC drilling machine for light duty PCB drilling. I would like to include a tool changer. I've been looking at tool changers and tool holders and they all seem massive BT30 ISO30 etc. These seem like overkill for PCB drilling.. The drill shanks are usually 1/8" and the hole diameters are all less than 1mm. Are there existing standards for smaller tool holders and tool changers?

Ideally I would like a tool changer that does not require pneumatic or hydraulics. So far everything I have seen needs pneumatics.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a shopping question.

Comment: Its not intended as a shopping question. It a question about technology and standards.